# Does firebase storage automatically scan for infected files?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I tried googling  but I can only find information about Google drive scanning files with file size less than 25MB. Does firebase storage do the same? I'm planning to build an app and want to ensure that users don't upload infected files. I'm checking if I have to implement virus scanning myself.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Storage isn't concerned with, and will not change the contents of, the data you put in it.  You do, however, have an obligation to honor the [Google Cloud terms of service](https://cloud.google.com/terms/).

If you want to scan the files for whatever reason, you have to do that yourself.